# Count of item in column compared to count in another column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, countif, gs-conditional-formatting, gs-vlookup

I have column A with a list of names, and another column B of names. I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the names in column A that occur more in B. I have provided an example below

My current function is not working correctly, for some reason

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,C3) > COUNTIF(E:E,E3)
```

[image]

In the example, John occurs twice in column A. John only occurs 1 time in column B, since John occurs more in column A than in column B the cells that contain John will get highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>VLOOKUP(A1, {C:C, COUNTIF(C:C, C:C)}, 2, 0))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that also works if a name only exists in column A:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A:A, A2)>IF(ISNUMCER(VLOOKUP(A2, {C:C, COUNTIF(C:C, C:C)}, 2, 0)),VLOOKUP(A2, {C:C, COUNTIF(C:C, C:C)}, 2, 0),0))
```

[image]